# sendAsynchronousRequest deprecation in iOS 9 and using it in iOS 10 with OperationQueue

Tags: swift3, task, ios10, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to download over 1000 images with total size of 50MB.
My code for iOS 9 was:

```
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue.main
    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    operationQueue.qualityOfService = .background
    for url in urls{
      let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
      NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: operationQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) in
          //image
      })
}
```

so I want to download the images one by one, but now in iOS 10 sendAsynchronousRequest is deprecated and I don't know how to add the images to queue. I saw different questions about using of sendAsynchronousRequest in iOS 10 , but I didn't find how to add it to queue. The most of the answers are to use `URLSession.shared.dataTask(...)` , but there you can't add the task to a queue. Any suggestions how to add all requests to operationQueue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLSession` is the right way to go.

Unlike in `NSURLConnection` where the request is dispatched on a queue, `URLSession` itself is dispatched on a queue.

Create a custom session with

```
init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration, 
            delegate: URLSessionDelegate?, 
            delegateQueue queue: OperationQueue?)
```

It's worth it to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession)